# Stripe checkout in Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, stripe-payments

I have tried using Stripe checkout in an Ionic app and couldn't get it to work so I ended up having to use Stripe Elements for my basic use case.
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout

My question is this:

Stripe checkout requires a successUrl and a cancelUrl when creating the checkout session.  This works fine with a standard web application, however it doesn't work with Ionic as it navigates to the Stripe checkout page in the browser and then attempts to go to the successUrl once complete.  However this can not take it back into the Ionic app.

I have tried using a deep link url to open the app again but the Stripe API rejects this as it only accepts http values.

I was thinking I could make a spearate success web page which it goes to that then opens the Ionic app with a deeplink to the correct location.  However I have not tried this yet.

Has anyone got this to work? Any suggestions?

Comment: i have use the examples on fireship.io successfully

Comment: One approach here would be to redirect back to your own server from Checkout and then from your server you can re-redirect with a deep-link into your application

Comment: @AaronSaunders Have you got the link?  I am a member and I am pretty sure it is not in there.

Comment: @koopajah Yes that is what I suggested in my question.   I just haven't used deeplinks before.  I will give this a try unless a better suggestion comes up.

Comment: @koopajah Just to update this. The success to a web page url then redirect to a deeplink does work.  However the UX is rubbish.  The stripe checkout is opened outside the app in the mobile web browser then jumps to another web page then back to the app this does not provide a native feeling experience at all.  I ended up ditching it and sticking to Stripe Elements which doesn't look great and has heaps less features but is actually in the app.  Stripe really need a mobile hybrid app solution.